# Wrong owner and group for files created under a samba shared directory

Tags: permissions, samba

I am trying to make writing to a shared samba directory work. I got a very weird problem. Now the shared directory is writable from a client machine. But the files created under the samba share directory have weird owner and group names.

I am writing to the shared directory as user mike under the client machine, but the file created always has user and group name as steve instead... Does anybody know why that would happen...?  Another thing I just noticed is that on the samba server, the files have owner and user name as samba, which I created for samba clients.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by different uid mapping on samba server and client machines it seems.